# Insert data to fields in document inside template or load document from template into envelope

Tags: docusignapi

Looking for paths to try, drawing blanks.

Is there a way to either send a template (and all its document) field data or to send a document from a template inside a new envelope?

I've found ways to do this if the file is local, but I'm desperate to have this be something they can still admin from the template portal and I can just pass known data values.

Answer (score 1):

Solved
...
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
apiClient.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient.Configuration);

```
        EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();

        envDef.EmailSubject = "stack test";
        envDef.TemplateId = mytemplateid



        List<TemplateRole> templateRolesList = new List<TemplateRole>();
        TemplateRole tRole = new TemplateRole();

        Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
        List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new List<TemplateRole>();
        List<Text> textTabs = new List<Text>();
        tRole.RoleName = "Sales Counselor";


        Text texttab1 = new Text();
        texttab1.TabLabel = "Buyer Name";
        texttab1.Value = "name goes here";

        Text texttab2 = new Text();
        texttab2.TabLabel = "Elevation";
        texttab2.Value = "AB";

        textTabs.Add(texttab1);
        textTabs.Add(texttab2);
        tabs.TextTabs = textTabs;
        tRole.Tabs = tabs;
        tRole.Name="Sales Counselor";
        tRole.Email="me@gmail.com";
        templateRolesList.Add(tRole);

        envDef.TemplateRoles = templateRolesList;
        
        envDef.Status = "sent";
        EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
```

...